# Socket error "code":"ECONNREFUSED" when trying to access remote server using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, connection, econnrefused

I am trying to connect to a remote server but every time i try to create a connection i get
Socket error "code":"ECONNREFUSED" , "errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":"80"}
My code is as follows:

```
//create the connection
const client = net.createConnection({
    host: urlObj.host,
    port: urlObj.port
});


//on receiving the data, print it
client.on('data', function (data) {
    if (verbose) {
        console.log(data.toString());
    } else {
        //get rid of the head of the response if not verbose mode
        var responseSplit = data.toString().split("\r\n");
        var inBody = false;
        for (var i in responseSplit) {
            if (responseSplit[i] == "") {
                inBody = true;
            }
            if (inBody) {
                console.log(responseSplit[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});

//send the request
client.on('connect', () => {
    client.write(clientWritingString);
});

client.on('error', err => {
    console.log('socket error %j', err);
    process.exit(0);
});
```

And I am parsing the Url here:

```
//parse the URL

var urlToParse = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1];
var urlObj = url.parse(urlToParse);
if(urlObj.port==null){
    urlObj.port=80;
} else {
    urlObj.host = urlObj.host.split(":")[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that your program is trying to access your own machine (= 127.0.0.1). Check the original URL you are feeding to your routine and make sure the parser ends up with actual remote URL.

Comment: Yes, I feel i am doing everything right but still it tries accessing localhost. What can i do?